# Why Do I get 404 Not Found in Flask

Tags: python, flask

For Flask every time I try to start the server I get `404 Not found` and it says:

> Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

My code:

```
import requests
from API import CHAT_ID, TOKEN
from flask import Flask, request
    
    
    
    
app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route('/call-status', methods=['POST'])
def call_status():
     call_status = request.form['CallStatus']
    
       requests.post(f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendMessage",
                        params={"chat_id": CHAT_ID, "text": call_status})
      return "OK"

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
```

I've tried to use different ports, rather than trying the same port 5000
I have even tried to run an even simpler ***Flask ***script:

```
from flask import Flask

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello world!'

if __name__ == "__name__":
    app.run(host="127.0.0.7", port='5000')
```

P.S I'm new to coding and all of this, if you could dumb some of the more complicated suggestions down a little that would be greatly appreciated

Response from Flask:

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2023 22:43:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2023 22:43:56] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2023 22:43:58] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Edit:
I added an `errorhandler` function to my code and started getting "POST" and "GET" `200` returned to me in the console. In case anyone else in the future deals with this, the errorhandler function will be below.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2023 14:56:30] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2023 14:56:43] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2023 15:19:08] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: The 2nd script _also_ fails?!? It doesn't greet you with Hello when your Chrome browser visits http://127.0.0.1:5000/ ? (Also, typo, prefer that address for localhost over the 127.0.0.7 you wrote in your question.) What console logging output does the flask app send to stdout? Did it successfully listen on port 5000, or do you have another app using that port? Maybe a leftover flask instance?

Comment: You get 404 by doing what?

Comment: Are you sure submitting a POST request?

Comment: @J_H Yeah the 2nd script also fails. I ran netstat -a in the command prompt and used XAMPP and they both say port 5000 isn't occupied. I will edit my post with the response I get from the flask app

Comment: @the__hat_guy yes, I used webhook.site just to make sure everything was sent properly

Comment: @no_hex I'm trying to access the server

Comment: Try using 0.0.0.0. it help listen all network card

Comment: @TanThien I’m at school right now, but when I get home I will try

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: Works great!

I am running this code, on a macos 12.6.2 laptop,
with cPython 3.10.8 and flask 2.2.2.

```
import requests
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello world!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port="5000")
```

In a chrome browser it greets me just fine,
and logs a `200` GET.

Either you aren't running exactly that code,
or some aspect of your hosting setup is broken
in ways the question does not yet describe.

(The logged console output was
very helpful BTW, thank you.)

Comment: Do you think it can be my pc?